# На какой слог поставить ударение: "сОлевая" или "солевАя" батарейка?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно ставить ударение: сОлевая батарейка или солевАя батарейка?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, *солев**а**я!*

Смотрите в [словаре Аванесова](http://slovarina.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0547.htm) и [на Грамоте](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9) (на второй только "солевОй", но странно было бы, если бы было при мужском роде "солевОй" женский "сОлевая").

Answer (score 1):

СолевАя. Она от слова "соль". Было бы от множественного ("сОли"), еще можно было бы думать. Но поскольку нет никаких оснований считать, что там в основе множественное число, то и сомнений быть не должно.